# did i correctly use the on_reaction_add event with Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

well i actually try to create a starboard with reactions. When a message is sent in a specific channel, my bot adds two reactions, one upvote, and one downvote, and create a thread under this message. As you can see it, it needs 3 or more reactions to trigger the bot, and if there are 3 upvotes or more, my bot post it in the starboard channel, but if there are three downvotes or more, the message is deleted.

But it seems that it's not really working, because the bot only add reactions and create the thread, the rest isn't working at all... And I don't really understand why, well can someone help me and/or review my code please ?

````py
import discord
import unbelipy as unb

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *, intents: discord.Intents):
        super().__init__(intents=intents)
        
        self.tree = app_commands.CommandTree(self)

    async def setup_hook(self):
        await self.tree.sync()
        await self.tree.sync(guild=guild_id1)

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction: discord.Reaction, user: discord.User):
    print(reaction.count)
    if reaction.emoji == "<:Upvote:1141354959372304384>":
        luxurefeed = await client.fetch_channel(1152700138540773437)
        total_votes = reaction.count
        if total_votes <= 3:
            print(reaction.message.author.mention, reaction.message.jump_url, reaction.message.attachments[0].url)
            emb = discord.Embed(title=f"<:Upvote:1141354959372304384> Feed", description=f"une image de {reaction.message.author.mention} a été envoyée dans le feed:")
            emb.set_image(url=reaction.message.attachments[0].url)
            emb.add_field(name="source:", value=reaction.message.jump_url)
            try:
                send = await luxurefeed.send(embed=emb)
                await send.create_thread(name=f"{reaction.message.author.name}'s feed")
                await unbclient.edit_user_balance(guild_id=guild_id, user_id=reaction.message.author.id, cash=1000, reason=f"envoi dans le Feed {luxurefeed.name}")
                print(reaction.message.author.name)
                await reaction.message.author.send(f"[ton post](<{reaction.message.jump_url}>) a été envoyé dans le feed suivant : {luxurefeed.mention}. tu as gagné 1000 <:LBmcbaguette:1140270591828570112>")
            except Exception as exc:
                print(exc)
            
        else:
            return

    if reaction.emoji == "<:Downvote:1141354959372304384>":
        total_votes = reaction.count
        if total_votes <= 3:
            print(reaction.message.author.mention, reaction.message.jump_url, reaction.message.attachments[0].url)
            try:
                await reaction.message.delete()
                await unbclient.edit_user_balance(guild_id=guild_id, user_id=reaction.message.author.id, cash=-1000, reason=f"supression")
                print(reaction.message.author.name)
                await reaction.message.author.send(f"ton post a été supprimé, tu as perdu 1000 <:LBmcbaguette:1140270591828570112>")
            except Exception as exc:
                print(exc)

    print(reaction.count)
    if reaction.emoji == "<:Upvote:1141354959372304384>":
        imgfeed = await client.fetch_channel(1152948287154966598)
        total_votes = reaction.count
        if total_votes <= 3:
            emb = discord.Embed(title=f"<:Upvote:1141354959372304384> Feed", description=f"une image de {reaction.message.author.mention} a été envoyée dans le feed:")
            emb.set_image(url=reaction.message.attachments[0].url)
            emb.add_field(name="source:", value=reaction.message.jump_url)
            try:
                send = await imgfeed.send(embed=emb)
                await send.create_thread(name=f"{reaction.message.author.name}'s feed")
                await unbclient.edit_user_balance(guild_id=guild_id, user_id=reaction.message.author.id, cash=1000, reason=f"envoi dans le Feed {imgfeed.name}")
                await reaction.message.author.send(f"[ton post](<{reaction.message.jump_url}>) a été envoyé dans le feed suivant : {imgfeed.mention}. tu as gagné 1000 <:LBmcbaguette:1140270591828570112>")
            except Exception as exc:
                print(exc)
            
        else:
            return```
````